# onClick iframe redirect to the src url

Tags: javascript, html, npm, iframe

I am trying to make a scenario where if someone clicks on the iframe, so it will open a new window to check the same URL on the web browser tab. But the scroll and other mouse events on the iframe will not affect it.

I tried different approaches but nothing worked

> Approach 1: Tried to get the onClick event of the iframe itself, but the issue is of cross-origin persist

> Approach 2: Tried to provide the onClick event to the parent element of iframe, but as pointer-events of the iframe are enabled it won't let the parent onClick to work.

> Approach 3: Tried to make an overlay of anchor tag, above the iframe. It did work but it stops the iframe scroll.

Here is my code:

```
<div>
   <iframe src="https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page"></iframe>
   <a href="https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page" target="_blank"></a>
</div>
iframe {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  pointer-events: none;
}
a {  
 width: 100%;
 height: 100vh;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
}
```

Fiddle: [here](https://jsfiddle.net/sumitTft/5jcfoa02/10/)

Is it possible to achieve this scenario with the cross-origin URL?

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not work because you have `pointer-events: none;` set to it. You can do like this that you click the "button overlay" and redirect the user with javascript, once it is clicked it "removes" the button overlay.

In my case I have set the background to be red just to make it clear, and I don't remove the button I just hide it. You can adjust to your use case. Also note that this script only allows for one of this iframes and buttons. If you have more the script have to be modified to loop through and add eventListeners to button and to look at its parent to add the class on the container (or if you just remove the button)

```js
const redirectAction = document.querySelector('.js-open-url')
redirectAction.addEventListener('click', function() {
  window.open(
    redirectAction.dataset.href, 
    '_blank'
  )
  
  document.querySelector('.container').classList.add('container--is-open')
})
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}

iframe {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.button {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: red;
}

.container--is-open .button {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <iframe src="https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page"></iframe>
  <button class="button js-open-url" data-href="https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page"></button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, @Dejan.S but it will work only once, after that it will remove the overlay. Also, the issue is if I make the overlay above to my iframe, It will not allow scrolling inside the iframe. Same as I mentioned in Approach 3. If I am providing the onClick to parent and making the iframe pointer-events none, then also it will work by redirecting to the other page, but the issue is because of pointer-events none, it will stop the scroll inside the iframe, I am trying to make both to work simultaneously if possible.

Comment: @DevProf not sure I get what you want to do. My code will have an overlay and clicking that will open up a new tab, it will remove the overlay and let you use scrolling inside the iframe. Is that not what you want? I had missed a ',' so maybe that was breaking the overlay and redirect. That is fixed now.

Comment: I want the same, but assume I am not clicking on iframe just want to scroll, in that case, that overlay block the iframe from scrolling. I am trying to implement like in the iframe I can scroll as well as if I click anywhere in the iframe it will redirect me to that src URL.